# more than one mapFragment with different markers

Tags: android, firebase, api, google-maps, tracking

I work with android studio app. there are 3 user ( admin , parents , driver ) each of them have to see a map with different markers but !! when I open the parent and driver activity i just see the admin markers !!
I try to clean the markers before I open the map but it dose not work

AdminMapFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admin_map_fragment, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the SearchView


        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ADMIN_MAP);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                adminMap = googleMap;



                MarkerOptions school = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(23.6045298658, 58.4443127667))
                        .title("School");

                MarkerOptions bus1 = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(23.62949, 58.22531))
                        .title("X128");

                MarkerOptions bus2 = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(23.650098, 58.196164))
                        .title("A211");

                MarkerOptions bus3 = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(23.625267, 58.245206))
                        .title("Q123");

                MarkerOptions bus4 = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(23.613507, 58.253369))
                        .title("W575");


                adminMap.addMarker(school);
                adminMap.addMarker(bus1);
                adminMap.addMarker(bus2);
                adminMap.addMarker(bus3);
                adminMap.addMarker(bus4);


                // Wait for layout to occur
                View mapView = supportMapFragment.getView();
                if (mapView != null && mapView.getViewTreeObserver() != null) {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            // Remove the listener to avoid continuously calling this method
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);


                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.6045298658, 58.4443127667));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.62949, 58.22531));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.650098, 58.196164));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.625267, 58.245206));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.613507, 58.253369));

                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                            int padding = 100; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                            adminMap.animateCamera(cu);


                            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                    markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + "KG" + latLng.longitude);
                                    googleMap.clear();
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
                                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
```

ParentMapFragment:

```
public class ParentMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap parentMap;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             @NonNull  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.parent_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                parentMap = googleMap;

                LatLng location1 = new LatLng(23.6045298658, 58.4443127667);
                parentMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location1)
                        .title("school"));


                LatLng location2 = new LatLng(23.642816, 58.211161);
                parentMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location2)
                        .title("Q123"));

                PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(location1)
                        .add(location2)
                        .color(Color.RED);
                parentMap.addPolyline(options);

                // Wait for layout to occur
                View mapView = supportMapFragment.getView();
                if (mapView != null && mapView.getViewTreeObserver() != null) {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            // Remove the listener to avoid continuously calling this method
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);


                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.6045298658, 58.4443127667));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(23.642816, 58.211161));


                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                            int padding = 100; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                            parentMap.animateCamera(cu);


                            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                    markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + "KG" + latLng.longitude);
                                    googleMap.clear();
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
                                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-display-locations-from-firestore-on-google-maps-using-jetpack-compose-9490c92c34da) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreGoogleMapsJetpackCompose).